# Duotone psd file for (offset) printing

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, rgb, channel, duotone

I read that answers at this question: [Preparing design for duotone printing?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/77708/18168)

I need it to be more specific about the step: *use the complementary RGB channel, in this case Red (E) Play with the contrast*.

Where can I find the compl. RGB channel while working in grayscale?
Also, in which way do I combine these two layers?

The result is fantastic and I wish to make it myself!

Comment: I almost rewrite entirely the other post so it is more clear the concept behind duotones. For the specific process on Photoshop, these answers are fine.
**More examples added!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer is talking about the complementary color of the image main color: cyan, which is red, the opposite.

The step by step is:

1. Search the complementary channel (at the gif example is the Green Channel)
2. Duplicate it and rename it (COMPLEMENTARY)
3. Invert it
4. Set the image to grayscale
5. Set the image back to RGB
6. Load the COMPLEMENTARY channel selection
7. Create a Color Fill Layer with the ink content
8. Change the blend mode to Multiply

[image: Animation]

<sub>This gif follows the step by step of the answer included in the question. It is not the right method for a two-ink printing, it's only the creation of a RGB image in duotone such as the explanation. [This other answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/112799/120647) shows more details about how to make a Photoshop Duotone.</sub>

Comment: Curious why RGB mode is used when the goal is offset printing? Had the same curiosity about Rafael's answer in the linked question. If you work in RGB to do this it inevitably gets converted to CMYK, not 2 color (duotone).

Comment: @Scott I was writing (and translating) the clarification to insert in the answer. It's a wrong answer for me too.

Comment: Dear Scott and dear Danielillo wow! thank you so much, very helpful. I thought that by exporting a file as duotone I could print only two colours and save money at the printing step of an edition. What about digital printing? Is it OK to print duotone?

Comment: Printing offset in just two flat inks is more expensive than a regular CMYK printing: the printer has to stop their regular production, clean their machines for those inks, prepare them and make this job just one time. All this process makes it more expensive. Digital printing regularly is CMYK inks and special inks for punctual jobs like metallic or white. I don't think digital print is prepared for flat Pantone inks. Ask your printer.

Comment: ΟΚ! In Greece, every plate is charged so less plates less cost, but I'm gonna talk to my printer. Thanks again, so much!

Comment: @Danielillo, that is only the case for offset printers who focus primarily on CMYK printing. For small print shops that have 2-color presses, this method is far cheaper than full CMYK process printing, and has saved my clients a lot on production costs over the years.

Comment: @Christos, Digital printing is almost certainly going to be CMYK, possibly with additional inks like white and varnish, but never fewer than CMYK. Digital printers tend to charge by the click, which is to say 1 side of one sheet. That click cost will be the same whether it is 2, 3, or 4-colors. The only way to save on colors is to run as black-only. This is true for digital printers pretty much across the board.

Comment: Of course, there are some digital printers, like the hp Indigo, that have reservoirs dedicated to specific PMS inks, but those are generally used at a premium price, not to save money!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not one to use RGB color more for Offset printing, and especially for *duotones*. If you work on RGB to create the perfect duotone, well.. that image will need to be converted to CMYK for printing. When it's converted, your (visual) 2 colors gets **split across the CMYK channels** and it's *no longer* a duotone technically. It may still *look* like 2 colors, but it's a 4 color image, not 2 color.

There are options for *real* duotones....

---

## 1 Standard Duotone

Start with a greyscale image:
[image]

Choose `Image > Mode > Duotone`. This allows you to pick a second color: 
[image]

If you want to adjust the amount of color you can alter the *Duotone Curve* for either color:
[image]

This creates a *real* duotone. Save as DCS 2.0 (or PSD) and place in a layout application.
[image]

---

## 2 Duotone with *different* pixel data per color

if you want *different pixel data* in a two-color image (still a duotone)...

Start with the same Greyscale image;

[image]

Convert the image to CMYK - `Image > Mode >CMYK` . Look at the **Channels Panel** and highlight the channel with the most contrast (often the Y channel). Select all and `Edit > Copy`. Then highlight the K channel and `Edit > Paste`. Now **fill** the C, M, and Y channels with 100% white, so they are "empty".

[image]

You may then need to highlight the K channel and adjust Levels/Curves to bring the contrast back to normal:

[image]

Now, from the **Channels Panel**, choose **New Spot Channel** and pick your color:

[image]

Then, if you want you can copy the K channel and paste it on the Spot Color channel:

[image]

And any changes you make to *either* **channel** with alter *that color specifically* rather than the entire image:

[image]

(Leave the blank CMY channels there.)

Save as DCS2.0 (or PSD) for placement in a Layout Application.