# Remove colors from image for two-color printing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I have a JPG image that to my eyes has two colors (black and magenta) but to InDesign eyes (Separations preview tab) it has also yellow and cyan (in lower levels).

[image]

The newspaper will be printed only with magenta and black colors, so I need to remove the cyan and yellow colors from the image. And also this is the image when I unselect the colors.

[image]

I am watching videos since the past two hours, but I can't make this work. I have tried editing the image with Adobe Illustrator, but there are no swatches at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: Illustrator is the **wrong** tool. Illustrator is not for editing raster images (photographs). You want to use **Photoshop**. What you are referring to is called a "duotone" -- this may be helpful--> https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77703/preparing-design-for-duotone-printing

Comment: or.. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/97123/printing-photographs-when-job-is-a-2-spot-color-job or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/116209/duotone-psd-file-for-offset-printing or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/84423/risograph-printing-separation-for-duotone-print

Comment: You may disable rich blacks and get your photo printed with k only. You should ask the printer how they want the PDF being constructed if it's printed only with  black and magenta. And ask a soft proof to see did they make it right.